# Flatten syntax with yield - improving code readability

Tags: scala, loops, flatten

I'm trying to improve the readability of my code and I'm having a hard time with this little chunk.

Foo is a method that accepts a List[Ping]

Thing.generate returns a List[Ping]

ListOfPings is a List[Ping]

hasQuality returns a boolean value from evaluating a Ping

Here's the code:

```
foo((for {
          pinger <- listOfPings
        } yield pinger.generate.filter(_.hasQuality)).flatten)
```

Each Ping in listOfPingss is creating a List[Thing] with the generate method, meaning the result of the yield at the end of the loop is a List[List[Ping]].

I'm flattening that List[List[Ping]] (not the individual lists), and putting the whole result into foo

I'm having trouble making this look nicer, potentially with a flatmap? I sincerely appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
foo {
  for (p <- listOfPings ; q <- p.generate if q.hasQuality) yield q
}
```